# Programming android,php,mysql connectivity

Tags: android

I got the below errors in my log cat whenever I tried to connect my android app to mysql using php and json parser. Can anyone help me in this regard?

```
12-26 06:07:23.222: D/gralloc_goldfish(766): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-26 06:09:34.332: D/dalvikvm(766): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 89K, 7% free 2794K/3004K, paused 155ms, total 176ms
12-26 06:09:34.402: I/dalvikvm-heap(766): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.447MB for 635812-byte allocation
12-26 06:09:34.642: D/dalvikvm(766): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 7% free 3409K/3628K, paused 245ms, total 245ms
12-26 06:09:35.592: I/Choreographer(766): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-26 06:09:36.102: I/Choreographer(766): Skipped 109 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-26 06:09:36.532: I/Choreographer(766): Skipped 91 frames!  The application may be doing too
```

Comment: You should read your stack traces. Look for `Caused by`. And you might want to look into those skipped frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException` due to Json Error.

```
E/JSON Parser(766): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Unknown of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Check out at Line number 96 &

`com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(AllProductsActivity.java:96)`

Try to debug your code, Your JSON object getting null it mean your response are not valid as you have written code or as per requirement.

Comment: can u suggest me a tutorial to connect my android app to mysql using php.

Comment: http://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/2013/05/27/83/ check my sample example

Comment: have you check that example ?

Comment: I AM GOING Through that example.i will notify later when i will complete it .